# Table in desired format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reshape the table in accordance with my needs. Below you can see a small example of my data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('max_columns', None)

data = {
        'type_sale': ['open','closed'],
        'group_1': [20,10],
        'group_2': [20,10],
        'group_3': [20,10],
        'group_4': [20,10],
        'group_5': [20,10],
        'group_6': [20,10],
        'group_7': [20,10],
        'group_8': [20,10],
        'group_9': [20,10],
        'group_10': [20,10],
        }


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['type_sale',
                                   'group_1',
                                   'group_2',
                                   'group_3',
                                   'group_4',
                                   'group_5',
                                   'group_6',
                                   'group_7',
                                   'group_8',
                                   'group_9',
                                   'group_10',
                                   ])
```

Now I would like to change the table in the format described below

[image]

I tried with this line of code but I can't get the desired format shown in the pic above.

```
df1=df.melt(id_vars=["type_sale"],var_name="groups")
```

So can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest in my opinion, [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
out = df.set_index('type_sale').T
```

or:

```
out = df.set_index('type_sale').rename_axis(None).T
```

output:

```
          open  closed
group_1     20      10
group_2     20      10
group_3     20      10
group_4     20      10
group_5     20      10
group_6     20      10
group_7     20      10
group_8     20      10
group_9     20      10
group_10    20      10
```